# Probability of words appearing at specific area in string

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I was linked a youtube video where the first two characters were underscores, how could I calculate the probability of that happening? 64 possible characters, 11 character long string, and only two underscores appearing twice at the beginning. Is this possible?

Comment: Probability under what distribution? It’d be impossible in a language that doesn't use it, and quite likely if it's a Morse code written using “.” and “_”.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that all characters are equally likely to appear at any position (not likely for any "real" language, but probably a reasonable assumption for auto-generated URLs), then the probability for an underscore at any particular position is $\frac{1}{64}$.

If you also assume that characters are independent (again see above), then the probability for *two* underscores is $\frac{1}{64}\times\frac{1}{64}\approx 0.0002$.

Comment: This assumption alone does not determine your answer.  You are implicitly assuming the characters are drawn *independently.* For a common application where the characters meet your initial assumption but are *not* independent, see any of our [threads about Scrabble](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=scrabble).

Comment: @whuber: I write in my second paragraph that *if* we can assume independence, the result follows. Where is my error?

Comment: Sorry -- I was looking for assumptions at the outset and overlooked your clearly stated assumption in the second paragraph!  +1.